# Use a string (multivalued field from table) as where clause in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I try to redefine a SQL query with VBA to include the content of a multivalued table field as a where clause but I can't get it to work.

First I gather all the values from the specific multivalued field (formatted as text, can't use numbers due limitations during the import)

```
BLPN_Query = DLookup("Kostenstellen_Report", "Optionen_Reportgenerierung", "ID=1")
```

MsgBox will return this (mind the space between ";" and the next text): 
34; 44

This string can contain several different text entries. I would like to use the string "BLPN_Query" as a where clause condition. What I've got so far is this:

```
"WHERE (PROKALK.NK_STK>0) AND (PROKALK.TERMIN>{d '" & Startjahr & "-01-01'}) AND (PROKALK.BLPNR='" & BLPN_Query & "')"
```

If there is only one entry it works, but in case there are more than one it won't work (obviously). Not sure but I guess the space between the semicolon and the next text is an issue as well as I have to use "IN" instead of "=" but I don't know how to do this.

Solution (thanks to Andre!)

1.) Get data from table (looks like: 34; 35; 36), remove the spaces and replace the semicolon by a comma including single quotes between the elements for the IN clause. Now it looks like: 34','35','36

```
BLPN_Query = DLookup("Kostenstellen_Report", "Optionen_Reportgenerierung", "ID=1")
BLPN_Query = Replace(BLPN_Query, " ", "")
BLPN_Query = Replace(BLPN_Query, ";", "','")
```

2.) Include the string within the where clause (and add a single quote before and after the string) --> Final string: '34','35','36'

```
AND (PROKALK.BLPNR IN ('" & BLPN_Query & "'))"
```

it's not pretty but will help us until we finally get the new ERP system and can replace all the old stuff

Comment: Why do you have a multivalued string field? That will make the query difficult. You'll have to make sure that the string you are creating is equal to the string that is being inserted, even a single miss match will not return you a result.

Comment: I know a multivalued field is definitely not the best way to go but that's all I get from another department :/

At least they can make sure the string I'll get is always looking like this:
34; 44; 55 or 26; 38; 67; 104 (always separated by semicolon and always with a leading space on the second entry (until the last one)

Comment: Why don't you link the tables (if required) and run a single SELECT query?

Comment: Well that was my first approach but as I need those data just for report reasons I would like to gather only the information I need without linking the table. The source is a pretty old program (but still in active use) so I would like to go this way :)
and it's only this little problem which prevents me from getting the stuff I want.

Comment: is the sequence of concatenation is predetermined? can you show us some example values which are not working and possibly your table structure?

Comment: see above, attached my solution (not pretty but functional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN (...)` expects comma, so you need to do:

```
BLPN_Query = Replace(BLPN_Query, ";", ",")
```

and then in the WHERE clause:

```
"WHERE ... AND (PROKALK.BLPNR IN (" & BLPN_Query & "))"
```

Extra spaces don't hurt. This also works if `BLPN_Query` contains a single value, but it doesn't if it is empty.

Comment: it's not working but I think (as far as I can remember) I have to wrap all elements with " ' " --> example: '34', '38', '38'

Comment: attached my working solution above, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Excellent. I wasn't sure if the single quotes were necessary, if they are, those two `Replace()` calls and the final wrap with `' ... '` would have been my suggestion too. :) @Moritz